# Azure DevOps public project access logs

Tags: security, logging, azure-devops

We have made an Azure DevOps project public and are wondering if it is possible to see audit logs for public/anonymous users. I can see a complete log history for authenticated users but cannot see anything for public users.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such audit log. Audit logs contain many changes that occur throughout an Azure DevOps organization. Changes occur when a user or service identity within the organization edits the state of an artifact. While a public project allows non-members of a project and users who aren't signed in read-only, anyone can view this public project only.

Since public/anonymous users can only view, but not change the project, there is no audit log.